# Best SEO-friendly approach for icon links?

Tags: seo, html, json-ld, fonts, icon

I'm having trouble finding info on this. I'd like to know what is the best way to markup icon links so Search Engines can make sense of it. Google's validator tools seem to ignore `title` attributes.

The following are 2 cases for icon link formatting I tend to use (be it in breadcrumbs or in other navigation elements)—using CSS `::pseudo` element on a `<span>` or `<i>` tag, or styling a character by applying the `@font-face` icon font to it.

I also started implementing JSON-LD in my project, so for things like breadcrumbs, setting the `"ListItem"` `"name"` seems to tell Google what the name of the link is—at least the validator recognizes it in the JSON-LD code. When combined with RDFa or other Microdata, Google did not recognize the name without a hack, so I'm sticking to just JSON-LD for now.

I'm not sure about other search engines, as well as best general practices when using icons for links, and if using JSON-LD makes the HTML markup irrelevant.

### Case 1: CSS Pseudo Element

```html
<ol id="breadcrumbs">
    <li><a href="/" title="Home"><span class="icon-home"></span></a>&nbsp; &gt;</li>
    <li><a href="/collection-page/" id="collection-page">Collection Page</a>&nbsp; &gt; </li>
    <li><span class="current-page">Current Page</span></li>
</ol>
<style>
    .icon-home::before { font-family:'my-icon-font'; }
</style>
```

### Case 2: A character being directly styled

```html
<ol id="breadcrumbs">
    <li><a class="b-home" href="/" title="Home">H</a>&nbsp; &gt;</li>
    <li><a href="/collection-page/" id="collection-page">Collection Page</a>&nbsp; &gt; </li>
    <li><span class="current-page">Current Page</span></li>
</ol>
<style>
    .b-home { font-family:'my-icon-font'; }
</style>
```

### JSON-LD

```html
<script type="application/ld+json">
    {
        "@context": "https://schema.org/",
        "@type": "BreadcrumbList",
        "@id": "https://example.com/collection-page/current-page/#breadcrumbs",
        "itemListElement": [
            {
                "@type": "ListItem",
                "position": 1,
                "name": "Home",
                "item": "https://example.com/"
            },{
                "@type": "ListItem",
                "position": 2,
                "name": "Collection Page",
                "item": "https://example.com/collection-page/"
            },{
                "@type": "ListItem",
                "position": 3,
                "name": "Current Page"
            }
        ]
    }
</script>
```

Comment: What does "search engine friendly" mean to you?   Do you want to make sure that a link with an icon passes PageRank?   Do you want the icon to show up in image search?

Comment: I don't know about search engines, but using a custom font to display icons isn't user friendly.    Browsers have settings to use consistent fonts.  (I have mine set to use "Deja Vu" for all website regardless of what the website specifies.)   Icons just won't show up for those users.

Comment: Not sure where you've been, but using icon fonts in web design has been a standard for many years now using CSS3 @font-face because it is efficient (one request for your icons, compressed formats like woff) and cross-browser/OS compatible. Even IE supported it using eot fonts. My question was making sure that search engines understand what the link is for, such as a `home` icon that looks like a house, or an `email` icon that looks like an envelope.

Comment: Can you use alt text for these icons?  That is the typical way to tell search engines what the anchor text would be for image and icon links.

Comment: There is no alt text. They aren't images. They behave as any font behaves. The only difference being that instead of spelling out words, the characters are symbols. This is why I posed the question, since adding an `alt` attribute to an `<a>` tag or `<span>` tag is invalid HTML. I came across a brief article last night about using hidden aria spans. If I find anything more detailed I will post my findings.

Comment: They are custom symbols.  Only a sighted person would be able to figure out what they represent.    Providing an alternative textual representation would be good for search engines and blind users.

Comment: I really don't understand this reasoning. I can't replace company logos with text. Some are social media logos/icons and UI controls as well. I'll keep looking for a solution for what others are doing when using icons and other elements like this so search engines and screen readers can make sense of it. You can't always put text next to or in place of icons and UI elements or it will destroy the design or simply not fit. Thanks for your time regardless.

Comment: A company logo should have alt text of the name of the company.  Social media icons should have alt text with the name of the social media company.   A link to the home page with a house icon should have "home" alt text.   UI controls should have alt text with the name of the control, for example "play" for a play button.    Alt text only shows up in place of the image when the image can't be loaded.  It needs to fit, even if  it messes up the the design, to make the site usable to the visually impaired and search engines. Neither blind users nor search engines care about pixel perfect design.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I still haven't found a clear answer for making icon links easily crawlable, however using JSON-LD the schema validators at least show the search engines will see the schema if you set it up correctly and know the name of the icon link that way.

As far as accessibility, all you need to do is add an `aria-label` to your icon link and screen readers will see it. From what I've read, `title` attributes don't seem to work all the time, so adding an `aria-label` is the best bet.

```html
<!-- Old code -->
<li><a href="/" title="Home"><span class="icon-home"></span></a>&nbsp; &gt;</li>

<!-- New code with aria label-->
<li><a href="/" title="Home" aria-label="Go to homepage"><span class="icon-home"></span></a>&nbsp; &gt;</li>
```